# Ubuntu server fresh installation keep crashing

Tags: server, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on a Proliant DL360p G8 (non EUFI) and I'm facing many issues.

Before continuing, on a different HDD I installed Lubuntu 22.04 without any problem just a little of attention about hard disk space partitioning in manual mode

With server installation somehow I managed 2 time to end the installation. Both time at reboot there was a kernel panic situation coming from filesystem issues
Since then I keep trying fresh installation using different partitions setting on the HDD (4TB)

The installation process always crashes after testing the repository. I changed ubuntu server version and I changed USB media.

On the back of my mind I'm thinking there could be an HDD issue. How to test?

With the installation I used the Smart array settings to partition the HDD as do it attaching the HDD as external media to an ubuntu machine and format it using Disk and Gparted app

At the moment I'm really in the blind.

my aim is to install Ubuntu Server to test it with cockpit and manage VM or to move to Proxmox. I'd prefer ubuntu+cockpit because I'm more familiar with Ubuntu than Debian.

Is there anyone who could give some directions for investigation?

thanks a lot

EXTRAS

- install ubuntu server 22.04
- i tried on different HDD and it went smooth so I believe the installation issue was somewhere in the HDD health or table of partition so far I tried few confs which might have messed up
- proxmox: I tried on the'faulty' HDD and the installation hang or more likely was taking more than regular installation time whilest preparing the partition

At the moment things are working and I'll check the SMART option for the HDD health test

Comment: These are just thoughts that maybe helpful; to explore HDD health use SMART (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools).  You weren't specific with Lubuntu/Ubuntu Server details; Lubuntu 22.04 & 22.04.1 use the GA stack which is identical to Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS ISOs, however 22.04.2 & higher use HWE thus different to Ubuntu Server; so this detail can help explore if different kernel stacks (ie. kernel modules or *drivers*) were involved as you weren't clear. You mention SMART array settings in relation to partitioning; I'm lost here.  I'd switch to terminal & look for clues

Comment: Ubuntu Server uses `subiquity` which is a *snap* based installer which I find a little harder to find clues on, but regardless just exploring the system using generic POSIX (linux/unix type) commands will generally provide clues (ie. an OS is just an OS so basic commands reveal details), eg. you may find details using `dmesg` or `journactl` for clues if the system is struggling with something etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. I can answer only to the "HDD testing" part of the question, since you asked many things at once. Start with a live installation media on USB and use the "Disk" system app and check the SMART settings to see if there are any hardware issues in the disk
2. I usually install servers always on hardware or software RAID redundant disks (RAID 1, 5, 6 or 10) precisely to avoid hardware problems on the disks.
3. try to install Proxomx for testing purpose: the process is very easy and quick. See if are there real hardware issues or just software ones: if it works for Proxmox/Debian, it should work for Ubuntu too.